# Finding repeated occurrences with ranking functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ranking-functions

Please help me generate the following query i've been struggling with for some time now. Lets' say I have a simple table with month number and information whether there were any failed events in this particular month

Below a script to generate sample data:

```
WITH DATA(Month, Success) AS
(
    SELECT  1, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT  2, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT  3, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT  4, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT  5, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT  6, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT  7, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT  8, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT  9, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 13, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 14, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 15, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 16, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 17, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 18, 0
)
```

Given the definition of a "repeated failure ":

When event failure occurs during at least 4 months in any 6 months period then the last month with such failure is a "repeated failure" my query should return the following output

```
Month   Success RepeatedFailure
1       0   
2       0   
3       0   
4       1   
5       1   
6       0       R1
7       0       R2
8       1   
9       0   
10      1   
11      0       R3
12      1   
13      0   
14      1   
15      0   
16      1   
17      0
18      0       R1
```

where:

- R1 -1st repeated failure in month no 6 (4 failures in last 6 months).
- R2 -2nd repeated failure in month no 7 (4 failures in last 6 months).
- R3 -3rd repeated failure in month no 11 (4 failures in last 6 months).

R1 -again 1st repeated failure in month no 18 because Repeated Failures should be again numbered from the beginning when new Repeated Failure occurs for the first time in last 6 reporting periods

Repeated Failures are numerated consecutively because based on its number i must apply appropriate multiplier:

- 1st repated failure - X2
- 2nd repeated failure - X4
- 3rd and more repeated failure -X5.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? 2012 has additional ranking functions compared to 2005-2008.

Comment: Hi we're using SQL Server 2008

Comment: I've edited your data to (I think) fix it - please edit further if I've made a mistake

Comment: Ok now they're correct, thanks AakashM

Comment: Considering months 6-12. If 11 and 12's success values were swapped, would 12 be labelled R2 or R3? (I could see it being either - R2 because it only has one other repeated failure in the past 6 months, or R3 because that previous failure was labelled R2).

Comment: Damien after swapping the values the 12 would not be considered as repeated fail because it wouldnt match the definition ("When event failure occurs during at least 4 months in any 6 months period"). The 6 months period from 7 to 12 (inclusive) would then have the following sequence 0, 1, 0,1, 1, 0 containing only 3 failed periods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this can be improved, but it works. We essentially do two passes - the first to establish repeated failures, the second to establish what *kind* of repeated failure each is. Note that `Intermediate2` can definitely be done away with, I've only separated it out for clarity. All the code is one statement, my explanation is interleaved:

```
;WITH DATA(Month, Success) AS
-- assuming your data  as defined (with my edit)
,Intermediate AS 
(
SELECT
    Month,
    Success,
    -- next column for illustration only
    (SELECT SUM(Success) 
     FROM DATA hist 
     WHERE curr.Month - hist.Month BETWEEN 0 AND 5) 
        AS SuccessesInLastSixMonths,
    -- next column for illustration only
    6 - (SELECT SUM(Success) 
     FROM DATA hist 
     WHERE curr.Month - hist.Month BETWEEN 0 AND 5) 
        AS FailuresInLastSixMonths,
    CASE WHEN 
            (6 - (SELECT SUM(Success) 
                    FROM DATA hist 
                    WHERE curr.Month - hist.Month BETWEEN 0 AND 5)) 
            >= 4 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
    END AS IsRepeatedFailure
FROM DATA curr 
-- No real data until month 6
WHERE curr.Month > 5
)
```

At this point we have established, for each month, whether it's a repeated failure, by counting the failures in the six months up to and including it.

```
,Intermediate2 AS
(
SELECT 
    Month,
    Success,
    IsRepeatedFailure,
    (SELECT SUM(IsRepeatedFailure) 
        FROM Intermediate hist 
        WHERE curr.Month - hist.Month BETWEEN 0 AND 5) 
        AS RepeatedFailuresInLastSixMonths
FROM Intermediate curr
)
```

Now we have counted the number of **repeated** failures in the six months leading up to now

```
SELECT
    Month,
    Success,
    CASE IsRepeatedFailure 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'R' + CONVERT(varchar, RepeatedFailuresInLastSixMonths) 
        ELSE '' END
    AS RepeatedFailureText
FROM Intermediate2
```

so we can say, if this month is a repeated failure, what cardinality of repeated failure it is.

Result:

```
Month       Success     RepeatedFailureText
----------- ----------- -------------------------------
6           0           R1
7           0           R2
8           1           
9           0           
10          1           
11          0           R3
12          1           
13          0           
14          1           
15          0           
16          1           
17          0           
18          0           R1

(13 row(s) affected)
```

Performance considerations will depend on on how much data you actually have.

Comment: Thank You AakashM. Work's like a charm

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH DATA(Month, Success) AS
(
    SELECT  1, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT  2, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT  3, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT  4, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT  5, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT  6, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT  7, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT  8, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT  9, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 13, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 14, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 15, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 16, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 17, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 18, 0
)

SELECT DATA.Month,DATA.Success,Isnull(convert(Varchar(10),b.result),'') +         
Isnull(CONVERT(varchar(10),b.num),'') RepeatedFailure
FROM (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Month) num FROM 
( Select * ,(case  when (select sum(Success) 
from DATA where MONTH>(o.MONTH-6) and MONTH<=(o.MONTH)  ) <= 2 
and o.MONTH>=6 then 'R' else  '' end) result
from DATA o
) a where result='R'
) b 
right join DATA on DATA.Month = b.Month
order by DATA.Month
```

Comment: Asif that's a neat solution but doesn't return the desired output. In 18th month there is a repeated failure but not R4. It should be R1. It is the first occurrence of a repeated failure in the last 6 months period (13-18)